# Unnecessary "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell" library preventing ClickOnce Publish from launching

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I'm a bit at the end of my rope trying to figure out this error, which occurs when a user attempts to run my ClickOnce application publish:

[image: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shall Version 2.0.0.0 isn't used by the application]

The difficulty is that I've gone through each reference branch in each project in my application and verified that there are no references pertaining to "Microsoft.VisualStudio" anywhere in the solution (this is just a sample of one of the projects, but I've verified that NONE have any references to Microsoft.VisualStudio):

[image: Sample of reference list]

AND I've verified that in the published "Application Files" any references to the "Microsoft.VisualStudio" namespace are set as "Excluded" from the build, as they aren't used:

[image: Application Files]

**How do I convince ClickOnce that, no, the application DOESN'T require Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell Version 2.0.0.0 installed the Global Assembly Cache?**

or, barring that, **is there a way I can include the specified files for redistribution with my application?** Setting "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll" to "include" in Application Files doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Unclear. The Design assemblies are shown as Include, Required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to finally address this by tracking down the specific version of the .DLL file it wanted (located in a hidden folder at "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll"), and adding as a reference to the project.  After hiking through the manifest file, I can only imagine that one of the other references included in the project somewhere has a dependency on that specific version of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll, although it was completely beyond my ability to determine which one.

While this seems like too narrow of a scope for this to be of use to anyone else, I'll leave it here just in case.

Comment: I'm glad you left this up!